# Common solutions to quadratic equations associated to self-adjoint matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hilbert-spaces, matrix-equations

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a complex Hilbert space of dimension $d<+\infty$, and let $\{|n\rangle\}$ with $n=0,\cdots,d$ be an orthonormal basis in $\mathcal{H}$.
Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a self-adjoint operator on $\mathcal{H}$ having matrix elements $A_{nn}=0$ w.r.t. the basis $\{|n\rangle\}$.

Consider the equations:

$$
\langle\psi|\mathbf{A}|\psi\rangle=\sum_{m\neq n} A_{mn}\overline{\psi_{m}}\psi_{n}=0
$$
$$
\sum_{m\neq n}A_{mn}(h_{m} - h_{n})\overline{\psi_{m}}\psi_{n}=0
$$
where $h_{m}=h_{n}$ if and only if $m=n$.
Let $|\psi\rangle$ be a solution to the first equation.
What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $A_{mn},h_{m},h_{n}$ implying that $|\psi\rangle$ is a solution to the second equation too?

Obviously, both the equations have the common solutions $|\psi\rangle=\psi_{n}|n\rangle$, furthermore, I can clearly see that, if there are $m^{\star}$ and $n^{\star}$ such that $A_{m^{\star}n^{\star}}=0$, then, the two equations have the other common solution $|\psi\rangle=\psi_{m^{\star}}|m^{\star}\rangle + \psi_{n^{\star}}|n^{\star}\rangle$.
However, I am not able to say anything else.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The solution sets generally won't be the same.  Try the example
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \\
h_1 = 0, \quad h_2 = 1
$$
In this case, the first equation gives us
$$
\Re\{\psi_1\psi_2\} = 0
$$
Whereas the second gives us
$$
\Im\{\psi_1\psi_2\} = 0
$$

---

The two equations have the same solution if and only if  $A = 0$.  Otherwise, suppose that $A_{ij} \neq 0$.  Let $\tilde A$ denote the matrix with elements $(h_m - h_n)A_{mn}$. Consider the two equations
$$
\left[\psi_i \langle i| + \psi_j \langle j| \right]
A \left[\psi_i^* |i\rangle + \psi_j^* |j\rangle \right] = 0\\
\left[\psi_i \langle i| + \psi_j \langle j| \right]
\tilde A \left[\psi_i^* |i\rangle + \psi_j^* |j\rangle \right] = 0
$$
in which we set $\psi_k = 0$ for $k \neq i$ and $k \neq j$.  If the overall solution sets were the same, then these two equations would necessarily have the same solutions.  However, by the example above, they necessarily do not.

Comment: Thank You, but, my question is about how can one give necessary and sufficient conditions for the common non-trivial solutions to be the same.

Comment: What does it mean for "the common non-trivial solutions to be the same"?  Aren't the "common non-trivial solutions" by definition "the same"?

Comment: The trivial solution is $|\psi\rangle=\sum_{n}\psi_{n}|n\rangle$ with $\psi_{n}=0$ for all $n$. A non-trivial solution $|\psi\rangle$ of the first equation is "common" if it is a solution of the second equation too.

Comment: So it seems to me like you're asking "when are the solutions that the equations have in common the same?".  The answer to *this* question is, by definition, always.  However, I don't think that's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, I explained myself very poorly. In essence, I am asking what are the necessary and sufficent conditions on the matrix elements $A_{mn}$ and on the coefficient $h_{n},h_{m}$, implying that the solutions of the first equation are simultaneously solutions to the second equation?

Comment: That's clearer. It's also not what you were originally asking.

Comment: My guess is that so long as $A$ is non-zero, these equations never have the same solution set.